# Add space between widgets WxPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

This is my code:

```
class TabTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resetButton = wx.Button(self, label="Reset")
        self.contactButton = wx.Button(self, label="Contact")
        self.copyrightButton = wx.Button(self, label="Copyright")

        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        h_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        v_sizer.Add(self.resetButton, 0, wx.EXPAND, 30)
        v_sizer.Add(self.contactButton, 0, wx.EXPAND, 30)
        v_sizer.Add(self.copyrightButton, 0, wx.EXPAND, 30)

        self.SetSizer(v_sizer)
```

How do I add some space between the buttons (`Reset`, `Contact` and `Copyright`) so that it doesn't look to much like it's been pressed together.
[image: Current layout of the buttons]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spacing/empty border for wxWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306808/spacing-empty-border-for-wxwidgets)

Comment: The answer Peter gave explains more than what you've linked.

Comment: The link provides a more generic answer and includes 2 extra methods to add space to a sizer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify a border when adding to the sizer:

```
    v_sizer.Add( self.resetButton, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, 5 )
    v_sizer.Add( self.contactButton, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, 5 )
    v_sizer.Add( self.copyrightButton, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, 5 )
```

Here `wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM` specifies to add a border to the top and bottom of the widget. I'm assuming you just want top and bottom; `wx.ALL` adds on all sides. Also `wx.RIGHT` and `wx.LEFT` are available.

The parameter following `wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM` (ie 5) is the size of the border.

See here for more information: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Sizer.html#wx-sizer. In particular the `Add` function and the `flag` and `border` parameters.